# Android unit test support does not work in android library modules

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, android-gradle-plugin

I am writing junit tests on android project using the new unit test support  http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support.

While the unit tests run on the 'com.android.application' module perfectly but they always fail on the 'com.android.library' modules. This has not been documented  in http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support . So I wonder whether I am the culprit.

When I write those tests on library modules, the tests can not find the classes on the module and always gives following errors:

```
package does not exist

error: cannot find symbol
```

The android unit test support is in experimental phase right now, but is there a solution to it.

**UPDATE**

I have added this issue to android issue tracker https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=161038

Comment: What gradle task are you using? Can you add gradle build log output? I have working tests in a library module with the same setup as for application module.

Comment: Thanks for the help Kriill Boyashinov. I did not change tasks in the android library module.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like the task to compile the unit tests doesn't depend on the task to compile the library code.
The following fixed it for me:

```
afterEvaluate {
    tasks['assembleDebugUnitTest'].dependsOn(tasks['assembleDebug'])
}
```

I run the tests using

```
./gradlew testDebug
```

If you don't want to modify your `build.gradle`, manually specify the `assembleDebug` task on the command line should also do the trick:

```
./gradlew assembleDebug testDebug
```

Comment: This is absolutely the problem. Such a simple fix, too!

Comment: This fixes references to library classes, but does not help with referencing "R".

Answer (score 2):

In my android library project I also failed to get the tests running. What I did was create a test application that uses the library and wrote tests in the application that call the library methods.

This might not be the ideal solution, but was the way we got this to work.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look over here https://github.com/nenick/AndroidStudioAndRobolectric

There you can run unit tests on libraries and flavors. And no you don't need to use Robolectric as `Gaurav Vashisth` stated. You can if you want to.

[Here is an example of JUnit test in a library module](https://github.com/nenick/AndroidStudioAndRobolectric/blob/library/core/src/test/java/com/example/core/SimpleUnitCoreTest.java)

Comment: If you had looked at the example then you would have seen that you do not need Robolectric and you can also run JUnit tests. https://github.com/nenick/AndroidStudioAndRobolectric/blob/library/core/src/test/java/com/example/core/SimpleUnitCoreTest.java

Comment: There are no android library modules in that repository.

Comment: Thanks will look into them

Comment: You can go into the library directory and execute `.././gradlew clean test` and then it will execute the test command only for the library. Or `./gradlew :library:clean :library:test`